# Cannot Locate mysql-bin.log and Getting Authentication Error

Tags: java, mysql

I am unable to locate `mysql-bin.log` file and cannot enable replication while compiling my client class. I'm getting an authentication error.

Can anyone help me to locate the file?

Thank You.

Comment: In your /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf in your master replica system you should have the path where you have the mysql-bin.log (something like **log_bin= /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log**) If you can access your system, you can see it with **show variables like 'log%';**

Comment: Improved title and formatted body text to make it appear better.